# Writing the no-flux boundary condition in terms of the new variable

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, boundary-value-problem

In the [this paper](https://journals.aps.org/prfluids/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevFluids.4.114202), at page 24, it is given that

> The no solute flux boundary condition at the channel boundary still writes (at first order in $\frac{\partial a}{\partial z}$ ):
> $$
> \frac{\kappa}{a} \frac{\partial C}{\partial \eta}-\kappa \frac{\partial a}{\partial z} \frac{\partial C}{\partial z}=0
> $$

What the authors are arguing is basically the following:

Let $c=c(z,r,t)$ be a function defined on $[0,L]\times [0,a] \times [0,\infty)$ where $a=a(z,t)$. Then the boundary condition
$$\frac{\partial c}{\partial r}|_{r=a(z,t)} = 0$$
is equivalent to
$$\frac{\kappa}{a} \frac{\partial c}{\partial \eta}-\kappa \frac{\partial a}{\partial z} \frac{\partial c}{\partial z}=0$$
where $\eta(z,t) := r/a(z,t)$. So $\eta$ is the new ¨normalised¨ radius and they write the boundary condition in terms of this normalised radius.

---

However, when I I tried the reproduce the same equation, I got a completely different equation. There is my argument:

Let $\bar c = \bar c(z,\eta,t) := c(z,\eta a(z,t),t)$. Then
$$
\frac{\partial \bar c}{\partial \eta} =  \frac{\partial c}{\partial z} \frac{\partial z}{\partial \eta}   + \frac{\partial c}{\partial r}  \frac{\partial r}{\partial \eta } +  \frac{\partial c}{\partial t}\frac{\partial t}{\partial \eta} =  \frac{\partial c}{\partial r}  \frac{1}{a} 
$$

so
$$\frac{\partial c}{\partial r}= \frac{\partial \bar c}{\partial \eta} a $$

However, this is quite a different result than what the authors got. What am I doing wrong?